# jQuery put request from node js (using to upload JSON file to myjson.com)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, json, ajax

I am a beginner in javascript. I am able to get json object from http://myjson.com/api in my html page using ajax by using:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/bjm28", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
       console.log(index,value);
    });
});
```

I wish to update the same json file with different values from my app.js which I run using nodejs.

I tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajax-request and "Update a json" column in http://myjson.com/api

```
var request = require('ajax-request')
data={
    "Man":960,
    "Woman":40
}
request({
        url:'https://api.myjson.com/bins/bjm28',
        type:'PUT',
        dataO:data,
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(dataO, textStatus, jqXHR){

        }
    });
```

All the methods I find are used for javascript running in browser (not nodejs)

Is it possible for me to update this json file through nodejs?
I am trying myjson because initially I was unable to load local json/txt to html pages due to "Cross origin request errors.."
My aim to control my html webpage through nodejs (lotion.js) for dapp.

Comment: You have to stringify the object you want to send as json yourself. Default `$.ajax` serialization is form encoded data not json

Answer (score 0):

For your specific question/example you can use the NPM Request module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

You should do the following:

```
let request = require("request");

let requestOptions = {
    // your options here
};

request.get("https://www.example.com", requestOptions, function(error, response, body)
{
    // process the response here
};
```

In the Request module documentation you can also find examples to POST information.

Hope this can help!